# Graph for high dimensional data in Mahout

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-analysis, mahout, spectral

I am interested in running the spectral clustering algorithm in Mahout on high dimensional data.  My question is how does one take a list of high dimensional data vectors and create a nearest neighbor graph?  Is this done in Mahout or are there map-reducable ways of doing such a thing.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing like that in the project, not for making a k-NNG. Spectral clustering, yes. Yes I'm sure you can implement this in MapReduce. The question is just how to do better than brute-force computing k-nearest neighbors.

Comment: As I understand, there is some implementation of k-nearest neighbor in Mahout 0.8, do you think this could be used to make a k-NNG graph?